# ScreenShot of view partially shown on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

For taking screenshot of a view, i am using this code

```
-(UIImage *)renderImageFromView:(UIView *)view 
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [view.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return renderedImage;
}
```

Now suppose my view is bigger than screen size and let say its rect relative to screen is {-100, -100, screenWidth+100, screenHeight+100} and i want to take the screenshot of my this view.
I am currently using this code:

```
-(UIImage *)renderImageFromView:(UIView *)view withRect:(CGRect)frame 
{
    CGRect rect = {-100, -100, screenWidth+100, screenHeight+100};
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, YES, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [view.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return renderedImage;
}
```

But the issue:
The final image contains screen shot of view from {0, 0, screenWidth + 100, screenHeight + 100} but i was expecting it to be {-100, -100, screenWidth + 100, screenHeight + 100}.

Any Solution?

Comment: Just to clarify. You want to screenshot something off of the screen?

Comment: Yes, i want the screenshot of content which is partially outside screen

Comment: I would expect the first method to work even for a view that is larger than the screen.. have you tried it?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Yes i did. But as since i am using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 0), this will make a context of screen size only

Comment: but `view.bounds` defines the context.. you mean there is something that is rendered out of bounds of the view?

Answer (score 0):

You have to first set that view into the screen with setting origin to (0,0) before that store that points in some temp variable so after taking screenshot you assign it back.

Now add that offset to width and height like if you view x is -100 then add that to width + 100 and set x = 0. same for apply for y.

now create `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, YES, 0);` and `renderInContext` and have the screen shot that you are doing correct. and don't forgot to set original frame back to view.

Hope it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is that the context takes just size, not the frame, so setting origin of the `rect` to `-100, -100` has no effect. I believe the solution is to create a context of size that is +200 points bigger in both directions, and then tell the view to render itself at point `(100, 100)` of that context. To set the relative origin of where to draw I tried to use transform on the view layer.

Sorry for using Swift, but I believe you can easily rewrite it to ObjC:

```
func renderImageFromView(view: UIView) -> UIImage? {
    let size = CGSize(width: view.bounds.size.width + 200, height: view.bounds.size.height + 200)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, UIScreen.main.scale)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x: 100, y: 100))
    view.layer.render(in: context)
    view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform.identity)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

Comment: empty image is displayed :(